# What is the proper method to programmatically create a copy of a sitefinity (custom module) contents?

Tags: sitefinity

We are using `Sitefinity 9.2`. We have created custom module for content storage. All our custom modules have fields like Customer, category and instructions. We want to have a feature to easily copy the instructions of an existing Customer and to create the same instructions for new customer.

We need something like this:

```
Instructions = Find customer X instructions(); 
for each item in Instructions {
    Create content for new customer();
}
```

How we can implement this within Sitefinity itself? Can we create a custom UI, where we can search for the instructions based on Customer Id and then can create a copy of those instructions for new customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you created the custom module by using the Dynamic Module Builder. 
If so, it provides an API for CRUD operations on items.

So yes, you can create a custom widget and put it on a custom backend page, that can provide a list of existing customers, allow the user to select one (source) and create a new one (target) by copying all (or some) of the properties of the source.

More general documentation:
https://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-dynamic-modules

You've probably already noticed, but in the top right corner of your dynamic module's definition page (/Sitefinity/Administration/Module-builder/module/type/MODULETYPE_GUID) there is a link that says 
"Code reference for XXX module" - that will provide more API examples for your particular module.